# Scaffold EF Core to existing DbContext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have an `ApplicationDbContext` context in my MVC Core app. Is there a way I can scaffold EF Core to that database without creating a new `DbContext`?

So far all I've seen in how to add EF Core is this

```
Scaffold-DbContext myConnectionString Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

`Scaffold-DbContext myConnectionString Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir yourcontextdir -Context ApplicationDbContext -force`

Comment: No, this command will recreate the existing `ApplicationDbContext`. As far as I understand @jDave1984 has his own code in it and does not need to overwrite it.
As I understand so far, there is no way to skip creation of DbContext.